# c# asp.net, dynamic drop list population after event, Save data in dynamic Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have made a simple code to show you my problem.

I have a dynamic gridview with a variety of controls.

I want the 2nd dropdown list to get populated with specific data which depend on the selected index of the first drop down list.

So for instance let's say we have droplist1 with 4 options so droplist1.SelectedIndex is 1,2,3,4.

When i select (option)2 there's the event triggered on select and droplist2 goes droplist2.datasource = **based on droplist1.SelectedIndex** , ( i hope you understand).

I have managed to populate the droplist2 after the droplist1.SelectedIndex event BUT i can't get the value to be saved...

I saw on the debugger that it goes till one point but after that the line appears empty on my screen...

Here's my HTML

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.WebForm1" ClientIDMode="Static" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="height: 337px">
            <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column1">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Category" DataTextField="ExpenseCategoryName" DataValueField="ExpenseCategoryName" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Category" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Expenses_NewConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ExpenseCategoryName] FROM [ExpenseCategories]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column2">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row"
                                OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>


            <br />

            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            setInitialRow();
        }
    }



    protected void Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }



    private void setInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;


        dt.Rows.Add(dr);


        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }







    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                    DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList2");

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = ddl1.SelectedValue;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = ddl2.SelectedValue;

                    rowIndex++;

                }

                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Viewstate is null");
            }
            SetPreviousData();
        }
    }






    private void SetPreviousData()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {

            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                    DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList2");

                    try
                    {

                        ddl1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                        ddl2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    { }
                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }




    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {

            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[(dt.Rows.Count - 1)].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[(dt.Rows.Count - 1)].Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList2");

                FillDropDownList(ddl2);

            }
        }
    }


    private ArrayList GetData()
    {

        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        arr.Add(new ListItem("Item1", "1"));
        arr.Add(new ListItem("Item2", "2"));
        arr.Add(new ListItem("Item3", "3"));
        arr.Add(new ListItem("Item4", "4"));
        arr.Add(new ListItem("Item5", "5"));
        return arr;

    }



    private void FillDropDownList(DropDownList ddl)
    {
        ArrayList arr = GetData();
        foreach (ListItem item in arr)
        {
            ddl.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: "variety of controls and with some dropdown lists", dropdown lists are not controls?

Comment: sorry tried to be more specific going from variety of controls to dropdown list.